# How to display more than four adsense units for an infinite scrolling page?

Tags: javascript, php, yii, infinite-scroll, adsense

I have developed my project using Yii, at http://kitchenking.ebhasin.com

In this project, I have implemented infinite scroll, and it's working as expected.

However, I want to display a Google AdSense unit every 7 pagesizes.

I know that one page can display only a maximum of four Google ads. That four Google ads are working fine. The issue is after the first four ad units, the rest of the ads are not displaying.

I added my condition here:

```
<?php
    $post_counter = 0;
    $addnum = 0;
    foreach($posts as $rec):
?>
    <div class="post">
    <?php   
        $rec_id = $rec['recipe_id']; ?>
        $post_counter++;

        if (($post_counter == 7) AND ($addnum < 4)) { 
            $addnum = $addnum + 1;   
            $post_counter=1;
        }
    ?>

    <script>
    // Display an ad unit
    (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
    </script>
<?php } ?>
```

Is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 4):

> **No, you can't.** AdSense allows 3 ad units per page, no matter how long
>   a page is. Therefore an infinite scrolling page is rather unsuitable
>   for AdSense.<sup>[1](https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/adsense/k30ReQMzuRs/I30MIul-qYUJ)</sup>

**Wait! But there are sites doing this, like *mashable* and *pinterest*!**

> Mashable is a *premium publisher* with their own set of rules, given to
>   them directly by an AdSense account rep.
>
> Regular publishers **can't do that**.<sup>[2](https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/adsense/k30ReQMzuRs/zp5xdll7xb0J)</sup>

Comment: suggest me any other possible lazy loader with adSense can implement

Comment: adsense are displaying.. i could understand that.. i want to get the id.. ie when i infinite scroll right.. i want get the next page id. the infinite scroll fetching the next page(ie next size 10) displaying the same page right..

Comment: Related: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/adsense/h-25mkt8QDM -- it's a damn shame though.

Answer (score -1):

Try to detach ads from parts of the page that are scrolled down and insert it in blocks that are visible.

Not sure that this should work but it's worth to try.

Comment: how to get the page ID.ie (next page ID). if get the page id then i will get the solution for this